# Create a non-editable field in Strapi

Tags: strapi

I have a project that sells products.

A product can have a price and optional: new_price. I would like to be able to sort them by price/new_price combined, meaning that I would need an additional entry in the DB like "final_price". I got an idea to create a non-editable field "new_price" in Content-Type Builder/schema.json and then update that with the final price for the product on "beforeCreate" in the lifecycles.js. However, I am not sure Strapi allows that, as I haven't been able to find a resource pointing in the documentation that it can. If there is a hacky way to do it, please advise. I am open to all kinds of other suggestions on how to do this Business logic as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way in strapi to make the field non editable on UI. You can go to `Content-type-builder-> Your component-> Configure the view`. And click on the text field. You can just make editable field as false.
[image: Strapi view]

Comment: is this premium feature?

Comment: I will use this with combination as @Chris's answer. to edit from using lifecycles and make non editable from the UI

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I found a "hacky" way to do this. I don't like it, as it is not that beautiful and sophisticated, but it does the job.

1. In product schema.json I added a

   ```
   "final_price": {
     "type": "decimal"
   }
   ```
2. In lifecycles.js, I created a new function that will calculate my final price and write it in "final_price" attribute:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     beforeCreate(event) {
       priceCalc(event);
     },
     beforeUpdate(event) {
       priceCalc(event);
     },
   };

   const priceCalc = (event) => {
     const { data } = event.params;
     data.final_price = data.new_price ? data.new_price : data.price;
   };
   ```
3. In the admin panel, in Content-Type Builder in Product, I clicked "Configure the view" and deleted the Final Price field from Displayed Fields section. This made the field hidden, lol.
4. Now I am sorting all products with sort: ['final_price:asc']

That is it.Hope it helps anyone!

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

(a) Add the field and forget about it being non-editable. You can calculate the `final_price` on insertion of an entry in your collection with Lifecycle hooks: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/models.html#lifecycle-hooks.

(b) Don't add a new field, but override the controller to return an additional field: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/controllers.html#extending-core-controllers.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thank you for your answer.

(a) Won't work, my client is not a tech-y guy, he will def override it when he forgets it is not editable.

(b) Won't work, as the controller will only modify what payload I return, but the value is not in the DB. And the "sort" query param will not only ignore it but will not return any data at all. 

I think I will implement a front-end sorting until this functionality is done 